# Translucent materials, like frosted glass, do have a refractive index?

Tags: visible-light, speed-of-light, refraction, glass

I'm an architectural lighting designer in Mexico and I know the basics of absorption, transmission, reflection and refraction of materials. But I can't find anything about translucent materials like frosted glass. Along with other translucent materials like acrylic and fabrics, frosted glass is a basic material we work here as lighting designers.

If you could explain this to me, I will be very thankful. Also, does anyone of you have any ressource related to the basics of refraction in translucent materials? I would like to further my research!

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

It is not the "material" which is frosted but the surface of the specific glass or acrilic panel. The material itself is transparent and has an index of refraction.

Answer (score 0):

The main effect here is scattering, which results in the diffuse appearance of frosted glass. The material does have a refractive index but the usual rules of refraction cannot be applied as the light path undergoes random direction changes in the material.